# Why is my Nitro PDF showing question marks instead of letters?

Tags: firefox, pdf

I downloaded some PDFs and opened them in Nitro PDF (version 8.0.10.7) but it shows me question marks instead of letters.

[image: Question marks in my pdf]

When I open the same pdf in Mozilla Firefox it shows me letters.

[image: Letters in my pdf]

I am not sure how that happens. Are there some add-ons which I should download for Nitro that would fix this issue? I tried to update Nitro but it states that I already have the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the font installed on your computer and the necessary fonts aren't included in the PDF. Firefox and Chrome download the necessary fonts (if available) on open. You can usually open the property page for the file to see what fonts are missing. If you're producing the PDF you can use font-embedding to prevent this problem.

Comment: I checked the Fonts in properties and here is the screenshot: https://paste.pics/0ae14162d795356821f55d2b8464f0ee

Fonts seem basic - Calibri, Arial - which come with Windows, and "embedded subset" is in the brackets beside every font. Does that mean that the problem is in stg else?

Comment: @Emersion I can only see the top third of the font list in that image. The fonts that are there are correctly embedded, but since it's only a third of the list I have to assume there are one or more further down that aren't included

Comment: The fonts below are repeated from this upper part of the list. I even tried to download fonts and windows stated that those are already installed. I installed Adobe Acrobat Reader and it can open the pdf and shows all the text normally. I must assume it is something with Nitro PDF specifically.
Thank you for your help @shawn.